# list all database in CouchDb view,validation functions

Tags: database, function, view, couchdb

I need a get a list of all databases in a Couchdb server inside a view/validation function.

Is there CouchDb predefiend function that i can use it inside function (like emit)?

I know i can do http request to get this , something like :

"http://server/_all_dbs"

but it is realy messy.

Thanks oren.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, within a view all you have visibility of is the document that you're processing.

Answer (score 9):

You have 2 way to list all databases in the CouchDB server

Without Password

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/_all_dbs
```

With Password

```
curl -X GET http://USER:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1:5984/_all_dbs
```

Comment: Couchdb documentation on _all_dbs can be found [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/api/server/common.html#all-dbs)

Answer (score 4):

> I know i can do http request to get this , something like :
>
> "http://server/_all_dbs"
>
> but it is realy messy.

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to make this less messy:

```
ccurl /all_dbs | jq
```

(The above uses [ccurl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ccurl) to make life easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Couchdb documentation on _all_dbs can be found [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/api/server/common.html#all-dbs)

API calls look like: `http://server_address:server_port/_all_dbs`